# How to create solr authentication in standalone java application with cassandra database

Tags: java, solr, cassandra

am new to solr, Please give me your valuable ideas.

and let me know how to connect solr in java applicaiton

Comment: What have you tried so far? See: [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create user authendication in solr with cassandra db in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397314/how-to-create-user-authendication-in-solr-with-cassandra-db-in-java)